# Your progress VS Team progress

Tags: navigation, progress

I'm in dilemma here. There is a big (can't do anything about it) survey a group of people should take, and when there are enough responses to make the data anonymous some reports are available.

I'm certain I want to make a user focused landing page, giving them the

- What is this?
- What should I do?
- Where am I/What's my progress? (they can complete the survey in multiple sessions)

I'm in dilemma about the Team's status. Should one mix both "your progress" and "team's progress" on the same page?

My first approach was to create a "Let's get started!" user focused page, and display how far they progressed etc.. but at the same time, the idea of showing how overall complete the team is sounds useful. Not sure if that should be mixed within the user focused page.

Sorry, I have no good mockups at this point. 
Any feedback is very helpful.

Comment: Hi there, this question is in danger of getting closed because a mix of 'not clear enough' and 'too broad'. There's too much "it depends" in any potential answer for there to be an objectively right answer.
If the team info is important, put it in. If it isn't, don't. 
The best approach here is to approach (ideally) users and stakeholders and ask the question "Is it valuable to show team progress in this view?"
You only really need to worry about the visual design _after_ you've ascertained whether or not a feature is actually useful.

Comment: You're absolutely correct. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps displaying the team progress on the landing page, and then again on a completion page once the user has completed the survey.That way they can see where the team is, in relation to themselves, at the start, then not be burdened with that information while they take the survey. They can then see how their contribution to the team has impacted the overall results at the end.

Comment: Thanks! Yes I thought of not showing Team progress at all while taking it. But I also didn't want to distract them too much on the landing page - so more of a secondary info design, maybe a link "Here's how your team is doing" or a full page dedicated to that state. Since my question was too broad I'm happy to have your answer which helped me along the way. Thanks again!